# how to delete all files that are old then X days and ended with number/s

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find, rm

we want to delete all files that ended with number with digit or more as 2 digit or three digit and so on

note - when files is ended with number , its tell us this file was rotate and actually backup with uniq number

example

```
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop    73668 Aug  5 07:56 controller.log.2018-08-05-07
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop    73668 Aug  5 08:56 controller.log.2018-08-05-08
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop   658893 Aug  7 11:53 controller.log.3
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop     1092 Aug  7 14:35 controller.log.2
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop  2750003 Aug  7 14:52 state-change.log.2018-08-07-14
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop     3678 Aug  7 14:52 log-cleaner.log.2018-08-07-14
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop   199094 Aug  7 14:52 controller.log.2018-08-07-14
-rw-r--r--. 1 kafka hadoop    24431 Aug  7 15:07 kafka.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop     1147 Aug  7 16:02 server.log.10
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop     1061 Aug  7 16:02 server.log.9
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop   135465 Aug  7 16:07 server.log.8
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop    10278 Aug  7 16:07 server.log.7
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop    10350 Aug  7 16:07 server.log.6
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop    10353 Aug  7 16:07 server.log.5
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop    10322 Aug  7 16:07 server.log.4
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop     1272 Aug  7 16:07 log-cleaner.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop   473322 Aug  7 16:07 controller.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop      170 Aug  7 16:07 controller.log
```

expected results:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 kafka hadoop    24431 Aug  7 15:07 kafka.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop     1272 Aug  7 16:07 log-cleaner.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop      170 Aug  7 16:07 controller.log
```

I try this option but this option isn't work

```
 find . -type f  -mtime +6   -name '*[0-9]'  -print -delete
```

please help me to build the right syntax ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-regex` parameter for `find`.

```
find . -type f  -mtime +6 -regex '^.*[0-9]$' -print -delete
```

This will match and delete all files ending in numbers (beware that some extensions can end in numbers too, for example `.mp4`).

Also note that `-mtime` does not support floating point numbers and always rounds up to the next day. So if you want to delete files that were modified at least six days ago you supply `-mtime +5`.